# Jetty WARs container - different class loader for the same class

Tags: java, jetty, classcastexception

I have a jetty server that contains 6 wars.
for example: a.war, b.war and more..

a and b have a dependency on x jar. both of them use the same version.

I have a strange problem:
when the jetty is installed on a windows machine on C disk, everything works as expected.
when the jetty is installed on a windows machine on **E** disk, I get "class cast exception" in line:

LogRecord logRecord = (LogRecord) loggingEvent.getMessage().getParameters()[0]; (72).

I see that one LogRecord comes from a.war with one class loader and the second ((LogRecord) loggingEvent.getMessage().getParameters()[0]) comes from b.war with a different class loader.

I want to understand what can be the root cause. and if I have a way to avoid it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Logging is tricky with isolated classloaders.

**Option 1: using the Servlet spec properly**

- Ideally, per Servlet spec, Logging should be isolated within the individual webapps.
- The `LogRecord` class should only come from the webapp `WEB-INF/lib/` location.
- The `LogRecord` class should not come from the server or system classloader.
- Logging events coming from a webapp should not be handled/appended by a server level configuration file.
- Each webapp should have it's own logging configuration.
- Your server level logging should use a different logging implementation than your webapps.

**Option 2: Breaking the servlet spec classloader isolation**

Alternatively you can complete break the webapp classloader isolation and force the logging classes to only be picked up by the server level classloader.  This is the iron-handed approach to managing logging.

Example:

```java
WebAppContext webapp = (WebAppContext)handler;
// System classes are classes that cannot be replaced by
// the webapps, and they are *always* loaded from the
// system classloader
webapp.getSystemClassMatcher().add("org.apache.log4j.");
webapp.getSystemClassMatcher().add("org.slf4j.");
webapp.getSystemClassMatcher().add("org.apache.commons.logging.");

// Server classes are classes that are hidden from being
// loaded by the web application using system classloader,
// so if web application needs to load any of such classes,
// it has to include them in its distribution.
// A negative pattern ("-pattern") means the class is not
// hidden from the webapp classloader.
webapp.getServerClassMatcher().add("-org.apache.log4j.");
webapp.getServerClassMatcher().add("-org.slf4j.");
webapp.getServerClassMatcher().add("-org.apache.commons.logging.");
```

The above can be implemented as a `DeploymentManager` binding so that it is applied to all webapps being deployed.

```java
import org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.App;
import org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle;
import org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.graph.Node;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

public class CentralizedWebAppLoggingBinding implements AppLifeCycle.Binding
{
    public String[] getBindingTargets()
    {
        return new String[]
            {"deploying"};
    }

    public void processBinding(Node node, App app) throws Exception
    {
        ContextHandler handler = app.getContextHandler();
        if (handler == null)
        {
            throw new NullPointerException("No Handler created for App: " + app);
        }

        if (handler instanceof WebAppContext)
        {
            WebAppContext webapp = (WebAppContext)handler;
            webapp.getSystemClassMatcher().add("org.apache.log4j.");
            webapp.getSystemClassMatcher().add("org.slf4j.");
            webapp.getSystemClassMatcher().add("org.apache.commons.logging.");

            webapp.getServerClassMatcher().add("-org.apache.log4j.");
            webapp.getServerClassMatcher().add("-org.slf4j.");
            webapp.getServerClassMatcher().add("-org.apache.commons.logging.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your detailed and clear answer! just to clarify: the LogRecord class it is an internal class under x - common jar that we created. so when I implement it  - should I add it like "org.apache.log4j." for example?